# galera_new_cluster: command not found

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cluster-computing, galera

I have installed 5 x MariaDB databases 10.2.8 (MariaDB database Server) on Redhat 6. I edited my.cnf to start with a cluster with 
sudo service rh-mariadb-mariadb start --wsrep-new-cluster, but starting failed on all the nodes

If I try with te command

```
sudo galera_new_cluster: command not found
```

Errors:

```
2018-08-15 17:44:24 140204929021920 [Warning] WSREP: access 
file(/var/opt/(...)lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
2018-08-15 17:44:24 140204929021920 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed

2018-08-15 17:44:24 140204929021920 [Warning] WSREP: (15ee6eeb, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') address 'tcp://(...):4567' points to own listening address, blacklisting
2018-08-15 17:44:27 140204929021920 [Note] WSREP: (15ee6eeb, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 15ee6eeb with addr tcp://(...):4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S
2018-08-15 17:44:27 140204929021920 [Warning] WSREP: no nodes coming  from prim view, prim not possible
2018-08-15 17:44:27 140204929021920 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,15ee6eeb,1) memb {
    15ee6eeb,0} joined {} left {} partitioned {})
2018-08-15 17:44:57 140204929021920 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
2018-08-15 17:44:57 140204929021920 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out) at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():158
2018-08-15 17:44:57 140204929021920 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():208: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
2018-08-15 17:44:57 140204929021920 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1458: Failed to open channel 'cluster' at 'gcomm://(...)': -110 (Connection timed out)

2018-08-15 17:44:57 140204929021920 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
2018-08-15 17:44:57 140204929021920 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://(...)) failed: 7
2018-08-15 17:44:57 140204929021920 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Spending a day now to try to solve the errors.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Well, if it errors out on not being able to connect with other nodes... it follows it is not bootstrapping a new cluster. Have you tried starting it manually (without using `service`) as `mysqld  --wsrep-new-cluster`? For the time being, you could leave `gcomm://` empty as well if you're just bootstrapping at the moment, that was the previous way to start a new cluster.

Comment: You only use the `--wsrep-new-cluster` on one node. Look in the init script to see if there is an option for new cluster (instead of start).

`galera_new_cluster` was introduced for systemd hence it isn't in RHEL6 (only 7+).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The solution for me this time: I de-installed the Redhat-standard-MariaDB-package-server, deleted all the tables and the cnf's. I tried to create the cluster first with ClusterControl, but that didn't work, getting al (very) lot of errors and a complicated my.cnf. Now clean installed the CentOS-MariaDB-version by hand, simple clean and no problems with RHEL6.9 and --wsrep-new-cluster.